# WiFi and Audio Malfunction After Upgrade

Tags: sound, updates, network-manager, 17.04, 17.10

I installed Ubuntu 17.04, three days ago, then upgraded to 17.10 the next day. Everything was fine until today. First off, I can't see a WiFi on/off option in the Network setting menu. I also tried playing a movie, then find another issue, it wasn't playing smoothly and there's no sound - I tried increasing volume and I got `Dummy Output`. I already installed everything needed for sound and all when I first installed the OS.

What could be wrong?

Comment: With so many issues happening at once reinstalling from scratch seems to be the better option. It's certainly the faster.

Comment: @MichaelBay Thanks for the response! I have tried reinstalling and whenever I boot from my USB drive, I get: `No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found !`. I tried using both YUMI and UUI but the error remains. What do I do now?

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0 also MKUSB can be used. In any case make sure the download is correct.